# How to run a command on a remote host from a Linux terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-server

The situation is like this:

There's a public shared folder containing command file on a remote server saying ServerRemoteA. From my laptop's Win10 cmd terminal I can run \\ServerRemoteA\sharedfolder\Windows\SomeCommand.exe successfully.

Now I ssh-logged to another LinuxHost and I should run its Linux version sharedfolder/Linux/SomeCommand on the same host ServerRemoteA, from the Linux terminal

I was refused to use "ssh user@host "command" " by the server. But I can run the exe version from Windows machine.

How can I do?

Comment: OK. Yes. I see.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to a remote host the program will run in the remote host, so the client does not matter if it is Linux or Windows. Thus, If you connect from:

```
Linux/Windows -> Windows: \\ServerRemoteA\sharedfolder\Windows\SomeCommand.exe
Linux/Windows -> Linux: sharedfolder/Linux/SomeCommand
```

if the SSH is in Linux if you just want to run one command you can use the following command:

```
ssh -l <username> ServerRemoteA "sharedfolder/Linux/SomeCommand"
```

Or if the server is in Windows from Linux ssh client:

```
ssh -l <username> ServerRemoteA "C:\\sharedfolder\Windows\SomeCommand.exe"
```

Comment: I don't know what OS is used on the shared machine. I got ssh error: connect to host serverA port 22: Connection refused

Comment: When I'm using Windows, I think the remote exe file is loaded into my local Win10 memory and run, right? How can I have the same effect on Linux then? I think the remote serverA won't allow me run the executable on it.

Comment: It means that in the port 22 the server has not listening any service, thus no SSH server in ServerRemoteA. I think that you are using SMB protocol and you can not run programs through SMB.

Comment: Yes, the program is running in your machine and it is loaded by SMB from the shared folder. It has sense

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that the ServerRemoteA not listening on SSH. So does that mean even I can run //ServerRemoteA/Path/someWinCommand.exe from Win10 client, I can't do the same thing from a Linux client, right? I had tried //ServerRemoteA/Path/someLinuxCommand and got error like "command not found".

Comment: Yes, you can not run commands via SMB. If you have a SSH server you can run commands in the servers. In a Linux client and a file shared via SMB you run these programs in your client machine too; but the file should be a Linux executable file and not a Windows executable file. That error is because you can not find this program; check it with ls command.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have got my answer from your information. Actually our IT team will mount the remote folder to my Linux host by individual request and then I can run executables just as on my own Linux machine. There's no difference as on Windows. Linux need to mount the remote folder to SEE it while Windows may have done the mounting from the back scene, right? Only if I have access permission.

Comment: Yes, you have to mount it. If the shared folder is with SMB protocol, normally in Linux graphic interface you can mount the folder for the graphic interface in the "Network" folder. If not, just mount command in the terminal. Your Windows mount it when the system start.